# SQL query for extracting records in sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.4

I want to extract the records which follow the sequence ON > WAIT > OFF based on the date. In this case result should return only record with key 1.

**Table**

```
    key  state  date
    1    ON     1/1/2018
    1    WAIT   1/2/2018
    2    ON     1/1/2018
    2    OFF    1/2/2018
    1    OFF    1/3/2018
```

Comment: Don't you mean ON < WAIT < OFF based on date if you wanted 1?

Comment: @Spade I don't think those inequalities are meant to be taken literally...just to show a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) such as `LEAD` and `LAG` in this case:

```
SELECT  "key"
FROM
        (
            SELECT  "key", "state", "date",
                    LAG("state") OVER (PARTITION BY "key" ORDER BY date ASC) LAG_STATE,
                    LEAD("state") OVER (PARTITION BY "key" ORDER BY date ASC) LEAD_STATE
            FROM    Table1
        ) AS a
WHERE   LAG_STATE = 'ON'
        AND state = 'WAIT'
        AND LEAD_STATE = 'OFF'
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d852c/1).

Comment: Nice answer - wouldn't you want `DISTINCT key` in case there are multiple records?

Comment: @Spade. Yes, `DISTINCT` can also be added.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to conceptually examine each record for each key, and check the integrity of the sequence rules.  A self join on the dates differing by one day would work here.  Then aggregate by key, and ensure that the entire sequence be valid, and that each of the three states in fact occurred by that key.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.key, t1.state,
        CASE WHEN t2.date IS NULL OR
            (t1.state = 'ON' AND t2.state = 'WAIT' OR
             t1.state = 'ON' AND t2.state = 'OFF' OR
             t1.state = 'WAIT' AND t2.state = 'OFF') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS label
    FROM yourTable t1
    LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
        ON t1.date = t2.date - INTERVAL '1 day' AND t1.key = t2.key
)

SELECT key
FROM cte
WHERE state IN ('ON', 'WAIT', 'OFF')
GROUP BY key
HAVING SUM(label) = 0 AND COUNT(DISTINCT state) = 3;
```

### Demo